# cakephp3 entities relationship error when login (the error is going after refresh)

Tags: permissions, roles, cakephp3

I am struggling with this issue for a few days. I've tried to debug step by step with Xdebug, but I cannot find where it is the problem.
Basically when login into the cakephp3.9 I get this error:

```
   App\Model\Table\UsersTable association "Roles" of type "manyToMany" to "Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\RolesTable" doesn't match the expected class "App\Model\Table\RolesTable". 
You can't have an association of the same name with a different target "className" option anywhere in your app.
```

As I mentioned above, I am using cakephp 3.9 and the **slince package** ("slince/cakephp-permission": "^1.0") to manage roles/permissions. After get this error if I refresh the browser evertyhing works as normal. The error only appears once, always after login.

**Relations** in UsersTable.php

```
  $this->belongsToMany('Roles', [
           'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
           'targetForeignKey' => 'role_id',
           'joinTable' => 'users_roles'
       ]);
```

UsersController.php

```
 public function login()
    {


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
          
            if ($user) {
                if (Configure::read('Options.status') == 2) {
                    $this->Flash->error('Please confirm your account - click on the validation link emailed to you');

                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login', 'controller' => 'Users']);
                }

                $UsersRoles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('UsersRoles');

                // Get User role_id
                $AuthRole = $UsersRoles
                    ->find()
                    ->select(['role_id'])
                    ->where(['user_id' => $user['id']])
                    ->first();

                // if the status of the user is false an error appears and it will be redirected back || check if is an admin role?
                if ($user['status'] != 1 || $AuthRole->role_id > 3) {
                    $this->Flash->error('Your account is not authorized to access this area. Contact the support team or check your inbox');

                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login', 'controller' => 'Users']);
                }  
              
                $Roles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Roles');

                // Get Role name
                $AuthRoleName = $Roles
                    ->find()
                    ->select('name')
                    ->where(['id' => $AuthRole['role_id']])
                    ->first();
                    
                $user['role_id']   = $AuthRole['role_id'];
                $user['role_name'] = $AuthRoleName['name'];
  

                // Set the use into the session
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);

    // Save the previous login date to the session and enable tour vars
                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

                if (empty($user['last_login'])) {
                    $session->write('Options.run', true);
                    $session->write('Options.player', true);
                }

                // Now update the actual login time
                $this->Users->updateLastLogin($this->Auth->user('id'));

                // Handle case where referrer is cleared/reset
                $nextUrl = $this->Auth->redirectUrl();
                if ($nextUrl === "/") {
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'Adminarea']);
                } else {
                    return $this->redirect($nextUrl);
                }
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, please try again'));
        }

        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin_in');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue it is in the relationship "Roles", it already exists in the file "**PermissionsTableTrait.php**" from the slice package, and it seems that cannot be two relationships with the same name.